# Eevee volumetrics different in render

Tags: rendering, shaders, light, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

When I was trying to make a cloud in Blender, I began to notice a strange issue. When the cloud is rendered using Eevee in the viewport, it looks fine. But when I render it, it looks much more transparent than the cloud in the viewport, as well as seeming very unrealistic. The cloud is made with a procedural shader.

[image]

## Viewport Render:

[image]

## Actual Render:

[image]

As you can see, the actual render is many times more transparent and also looks very "blocky" if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct volumetrics are a bit different in EEVEE. For some reason, emission strength is required to control the volume. As you can see, I upped the emission strength, then plugged the volume into the emission color, to make it constrained to the cloud. Have a try. You might need to  play with the values a little to get it just right in your scene, but it's a start.

[image: EEVEEVolume]